# C++: my switch-case loop goes to the first case

Tags: c++, loops, switch-statement, do-while

I am new to C++ so I am sorry for my lack of knowledge.
Anyways, I am trying to loop back to the menu after I am done with a case.

Currently using a do-while waiting for the bool "restart" to change to false.

```
do {
    switch (wahl) {
        case 1:
            std::cout << "Bitte geben Sie den Grundwert ein: ";
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin >> grund_eingabe;
            std::cout << "\nBitte geben Sie den Prozentsatz (%) ein: ";
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin >> przsatz_eingabe;
            std::cout << "Der Prozentwert lautet: " + std::to_string(prozentwert_berechnen(grund_eingabe, przsatz_eingabe)) + "\n";
            break;
            
        case 2:
            std::cout << "Bitte geben Sie den Grundwert (Gesamtanzahl) ein: ";
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin >> grund_eingabe;
            std::cout << "\nBitte geben Sie den Prozentwert ein: ";
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin >> przwert_eingabe;
            std::cout << "Der Prozentsatz lautet: " + std::to_string(prozentsatz_berechnen(grund_eingabe, przwert_eingabe)) + "\n";
            
            
        case 3:
            std::cout << "Bitte geben Sie den Prozentsatz (%) ein: ";
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin >> przsatz_eingabe;
            std::cout << "\nBitte geben Sie den Prozentwert ein: ";
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin >> przwert_eingabe;
            std::cout << "Der Grundwert lautet: " + std::to_string(grundwert_berechnen(przsatz_eingabe, przwert_eingabe)) + "\n";
            
        case 4:
            neustart = false;
            return 0;
        default:
            break;
    }
} while (neustart != false);
```

When finished with case 1, it loops back to case 1 and not the menu.
Could I get some guidance?
Thanks!

Comment: If `wahl` doesn't change then `switch(wahl)` will always go to the same `case`.

Comment: What is the value for the variable wahl before the loop?

The variable wahl is never changed, at least have a std::cin for the variable wahl at the beginning or end of the loop so that the switch makes sense.

Comment: in `case 4`, could I clear the console and display the menu again, and ask for input `wahl`? Shouldn't that work

Comment: You should ask in every loop iteration otherwise you may never drop out of the loop

Comment: By the way. If you return 0, you don't even need to set the neustart to true... return will exit the loop as well as the function where it is in

Comment: Ah makes sense now, I also just extended the do part up to the menu, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the value `wahl` into switch statement but you never tried to ask the user to get an input, so that never get changed and looped forever.

You can try:

```
do {
    std::cout << "Enter an option: ";
    std::cin >> wahl;
    
    switch (wahl) {
    case 1:
        break;
    case 2:
        break;
    case 3:
        break;
    case 4:
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
} while (neustart != false);
```

Answer (score 0):

> When finished with case 1, it loops back to case 1 and not the menu.

Yes, that’s exactly what you have written. When the `switch` is finished and `neustart != false`, the program loops back to the `switch` without changing `wahl`. If you want to go back to the menu, you must include the menu in the do-while loop.

Comment: works like a charm, I was about to start doing loops etc. but that's way simpler, thanks!

Comment: @Clark I am glad to have helped! If I, or anyone else, could solve your problem, it would be nice if you [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/217657) the corresponding answer (✓). See also [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest change:

```
do {
    std::cout << "Bitte wählen: ";
    std::cin >> wahl;
    switch (wahl) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you never asked the user to input a new value once the loop started, so every time the loop restarts the value of the wah1 is always the last one you entered before starting the loop.

```
do{
   std::cout<<"Enter another option:";
   std::cin>>wah1;
   switch(wah1){
```